# How to use better 'try' and 'except' in my code?

Tags: python

now i have this code and i need to use better the function try and except and improve the code, like which parts i should change of place

this is the beginning of my code:

```
contador = 0
name = input("Put the name of the file:")
while name != "close":
    validation=0
    try:
        file = open(name,"r",1,"utf-8")
        validation = validation + 1

    except FileNotFoundError:
        validation = validation

    if validation >= 1:
        Games=[]
        countrylist = []
        lines = 0
        File = open(name,"r") 
        line = File.readline().strip()
        while line != "":
            parts= line.split(";")
            country=parts[0]
            game= parts[1]
            sales= int(parts[2])
            price= float(parts[3])
            format= parts[4]
            Games.append(parts)
            countrylist.append(country)
            line = File.readline().strip()
            lines = lines + 1
        contador = contador + 1
```

Comment: You don't need to open the file again. Also, you don't close any of them. Best use the `with open(..)` idiom.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking for. That try looks good, but the except should print an error message, so that the user might know what's wrong. And validation=validation is as good as nothing, or am I wrong?

Comment: My teacher tolds me *the except should be out , but inside of a "while True:", but if i do this the code doesn't run @RicardoGuerreiro

Comment: It is already inside a while true, as long as the file is not called close. What is your intention exactly?

Me pudes explicar en espanol qual és tuya intencion?

Comment: @RicardoGuerreiro Ok, lo que quiero exactamente es leer un archivo que contiene datos, despues de esto, debo hacer calculos de cual es el porcentaje de ventas, promedio de ventas, que pais vendio mas juegos y cual fue el juego menos vendido, el trozo de codigo que envie, no es el codigo completo

Comment: Ok, bien, pero qual es tu intencion con try y except?

Comment: An except statement should either "handle" the problem, or exit because it can't be handled. In this case, since you are handling a possible mistyped file name, the except statement ought to print something like "File not found", and then a "continue", so you don't run through the parsing code pointlessly.

Comment: There is only one file? It's not clear as you increment `contador` (so I would expect there can be several files). If there are several files, the values of `Games`, `countrylist` and `lines` are lost after each file is read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly the objective of the code, however.

1. I had to work out how would the file be structured by the code 
   Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that the file is meant to have a list of parameters separated by ";" and each line being an entry in that list.
2. You do nothing with the data, in any case just breaking the file into a list of parameters and sending said list of lists back would be enough for a function and then you could do the separation later
3. So that I could see that the code was doing what I wanted I added a print at the end to get the result

This is the code I ended with I tried to explain most of the issues in comment (probably a bad idea and I shall be berated by this till the end of ages)

```py
# Why is there a global counter
# contador = 0

name = None # you need to declare the name before the loop

# check if the name is empty instead of an arbitrary name
while name != "":
    name = input("Put the name of the file:")
    # have the call defenition of the name in the loop so you can run the
    # loop until the anme is "" (nothing)
    # otherwhise if you don't break on the catch block it will loop forever
    # since the name will be constant inside the loop

    try:
        File = open(file=name,encoding="utf-8").read()
        # when using a function and you don't want to use the arguments
        Games=[]
        countrylist = []
        # lines = 0
        lst = File.strip().split("\n") # break the whole text into lines
        for line in lst: # iterate over the list of lines
            # seperate it into a list of data
            parts= line.strip().split(";") #make each line into a list that you can adress
            # elem[0] -> county
            countrylist.append(parts[0]) # here you can just append directly isntead of saving extra variables
            # same as the previous example
            Games.append(parts[1])
            sales= int(parts[2])
            price= float(parts[3].replace(",","."))
            style = parts[4] # format is already an existing function you shoudn't name your variable like that
            # line = File.readline().strip() -> you don't need to prepare the next line since all lines are 
            #                                   already in the array lst
            # lines += 1
            # contador += 1
            # you don't need to count the lines let the language do that for you
            # and why do you need a counter in the first place
            # you were using no for loops or doing any logic based around the number of lines
            # the only logic you were doing is based on their 
            print(parts)
    except FileNotFoundError as e0:
        print("File not found: " + str(e0))
    except ValueError as e1 :
        print("Value Error: " + str(e1))
```

For a text file with the format:

```
Portugal;Soccer;1000;12.5;dd/mm/yyyy
England;Cricket;2000;13,5;mm/dd/yyyy
Spain;Ruggby;1500;11;yyyy/dd/mm
```

I got an output in the form of:

```
['Portugal', 'Soccer', '1000', '12.5', 'dd/mm/yyyy']
['England', 'Cricket', '2000', '13,5', 'mm/dd/yyyy']
['Spain', 'Ruggby', '1500', '11', 'yyyy/dd/mm']
```